# SAS: Having a macro loop over an array iteratively

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

In my data I define an array as all the variables starting with `rev_`:

```
data df;
set def;
    array vnames rev:;
run;
```

And now I want to repeat the `means` function over this array. For example, let's say each element in `vnames` is a different class variable i'd like part of my command.

Let's say `rev:` actually expands to `rev1 rev2 rev3 revolution`

So I want sas to do this:

```
proc means data=df;
var rev1;
run;

proc means data=df;
var rev2;
run;

proc means data=df;
var rev3;
run;

proc means data=df;
var revolution;
run;
```

Now the function I end up calling might be more complex. I thought I should set up a macro and then run the array and macro together, but I have no idea how to do this.

I don't really have any sample data, but the idea is to run the same command (or series of commands, ie a macro) over a named array.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "means command over this array". There is a MEANS procedure (which can't run inside of a DATA step) and a MEANS function. Might help if you show sample input data and desired output.  Or try `proc means data=def ; var rev: ; run;`

Comment: Is there some sample data in SAS EG i can call up, like mtcars? I've edited the question to show what I really want.

Comment: sashelp.class is the most used sample data. Sashelp library is full of sample datasets. That said, your edit makes the question clear.

Comment: Thank you. I'd love some help that doesn't involve some crazy SQL paramaters!

Comment: Can't help now, but will add an answer tonight if nobody has beat me to it.  I see it as a generic macro language problem. You generate a list of variables from the data, then loop over that list, generating PROC steps.

Comment: I think looking at all the methods to create variable lists is important here, see the link at the end. You can use the colon, single hyphen or double hyphen along with the WAYS statement. There's also various ways of capturing the output. SAS does a lot of the looping required in other languages automatically so it's just a matter of learning how to do something most efficiently in SAS, rather than a direct code to code conversion or comparison. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom's answer is right if it solves your actual problem; generally, SAS provides a lot of ways to do things that don't require macros to brute force.  One PROC step will undoubtedly be faster than multiple.

But, if you do need to, the answer is to look at `dictionary.columns` or `sashelp.vcolumn` or even `proc contents` output.  Particularly since your list of `rev` variables is *not* just a numeric iterator (`revolution`), you can't just iterate numerically.  The `array` you define doesn't persist past that data step, don't forget - they're data step programming tools but have no use in macro language or procs.  `revs:` is still available in the proc of course, but `vnames[1]` is not.

Say your macro is:

```
%macro runmeans(data=, var=, out=);
  proc means data=&data.;
    var &var.;
    output out=&out. mean(&var.)=;
  run;
%mend runmeans;
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%runmeans(data=SASHELP.CLASS, var=',name,',out=M_',name,')')
     into :runmeanslist separated by ' '
     from dictionary.columns
     where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS' and upcase(name) like '%EIGHT'; *weight height;
quit;

&runmeanslist.
```

If you don't feel comfortable in SQL, you can do the same thing in a data step using `call execute` and `sashelp.vcolumn` dataset, or `proc contents` output written to a file.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to give an example using something like `sashelp.class`?

Comment: My answer does use an example using `sashelp.class`.

Comment: OK I'll mark it as an answer and try to use it. It's disappointing to see how limited SAS's looping capabilities are.

Comment: @vashts85 Then I don't think you understood the answer at all.  SAS has plenty of looping capabilities.  It also has *better* ways to do things than looping, two of which you have here in answers.  I still recommend Tom's answer as the primary one to use here, for example; it doesn't need to loop at all, and is the equivalent of doing something in `r` like indexing a vector using another vector (rather  than looping through the two vectors).

Comment: Thank you, I will look at his answer closely! And I wouldn't disagree that my understanding of SAS is pretty limited :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the `WAYS` statement in `PROC MEANS`. But your sample code doesn't match your description of what you want.  If you really want to find the means for all numeric variables and run it separately for many different class variables then this is the code you want.

```
proc means data=have ;
  class rev: ;
  ways 1;
run;
```

Comment: What if the variables in the array are not tied together in any way? For example, they are `test cat dog foo`. How would I tell SAS to do the `procs` over that array?

Comment: @vashts85 Then you need some SQL or CALL SYMPUT or whatever to define the variable list in a macro variable.  Obviously you need some way of defining that list or this is impossible, but whatever defines that list can be used to create a macro variable, using the `dictionary.columns` or other datasets as my answer describes - same general principle (just creating a macro variable to use in `class` statement vs. calling the whole proc).

Comment: @vashts85 You can use code generation. Either make a macro, use PROC SQL to generate code into macro variables, use a data step to generate code using CALL EXECUTE, or use a data step to generate code to a text file that you then run using %include.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using the `ways` in `proc means` to do this only once (rather than looping or multiply executing) without wildcard.

```
proc sql;
  select name into :varlist separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS'
    and not (upcase(name) like '%EIGHT');
quit;

proc means data=sashelp.class;
  class &varlist.;
  ways 1;
run;
```

Something more like that.  (I turn the class statement around here and use height/weight for VAR and class variables the non-numerics, as that makes more sense).

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggest, there's probably a better way to get what you need in the larger context of your project. That being said, I thought `call execute()` was worth a mention as it comes close to what you were particularly looking for.

```
%macro SomeProc(dataset,variable);
    proc univariate data=&dataset.;
        var &variable.;
    run;
%mend SomeProc;

data _null_;
    set sashelp.Cars end=lastObs;
    array vnames[*] MPG_:;
    if lastObs then do i=1 to dim(vnames);
        call execute('%SomeProc(sashelp.Cars,'||vname(vnames[i])||')');
    end;
run;
```